# having difficulty with managing widgets

Tags: qt

I Have a Class Named "Student" (this class dose have Form)
And In my MainWindow I have A QVector From This Class !
Now I want To Show The form Of each Member Of the QVector But I Can't !
(I'm Doing this because I want that any Student have an Special Page For it self ! Witch saves any Change especial For themselves)
This Is my Code :

In My Main Window :

```
StHead = new QVector <Student> ;

void MainWindow::StudentSignIn (QString User,QString Pass)
{
///////Sign in things !
    int index = StudentSearch(User);
    Student* at = StHead->data();
    if (at[index].GetPass() == Pass)
        emit Hide_StuLog();
    qDebug()<<"This Slot happens";
    (*StHead)[index].show();
}
```

BUT , When it shows , it's An empty page !
What the problem ?! Is What I'm doing Even Possible ?!

And this is Also how I add Member To my QVector

```
void MainWindow::StudentAdder(Student s)
{
    StHead->append(s);
}
```

Comment: If the top-level widget is appearing, but it contains no other widgets, then the problem code is with the `Student` class.  As a side note, there's almost never a good reason to create containers on the heap - so why are you?

Comment: Add the definition of Student. Is it a QWidget? Or is Student::show() your own method?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lots of things are not good practices:

1. As stated, do not use a vector declared like`QVector<Student> * StHead;`, but directly a `QVector<Student> StHead;`
2. At the contrary, if Student are inheriting QObject, and in particular QWidget, you may rather allocate them on the heap, hence you have in fact `QVector<Student *> StHead;`
3. Access the vector directly with StHead[index], your call using `data()` is rather painful for the eye ;)
4. When you call `StHead[index]->show()`, make sure the parent of the widget to be shown is already visible, unless it has no parent (call `StHead[index]->parent()` if you're not sure).